# jQuery mmenu plugin - Change menu width size

Tags: jquery, mmenu

Does anyone know a way to change the default nav width size of the jquery mmenu plugin. I can't seem to find where to edit the size within the source code. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try to override the default style as per below:

```
.mm-menu {
    width:320px !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, adn the menu was the desired width, but the content was still moved over 440px instead of the 320px.  Any clues?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding custom css for both  .mm-menu width  &  mm-opening .mm-slideout
The code below is for responsive widths, with small screen size at 140px wide.

```
.mm-menu{width:80%;min-width:140px; }

 @media all and (min-width:550px){.mm-menu{width:80%;min-width:140px;max-width:300px}
}

@media all and (min-width:1024px){.mm-menu{width:80%;min-width:140px;max-width:440px}
}



html.mm-opening .mm-slideout{-webkit-transform:translate3d(80%,0,0);transform:translate3d(80%,0,0)}
@media all and (max-width:175px){html.mm-opening .mm-slideout{-webkit-transform:translate3d(140px,0,0);transform:translate3d(140px,0,0)}
}
@media all and (min-width:550px){html.mm-opening .mm-slideout{-webkit-transform:translate3d(300px,0,0);transform:translate3d(300px,0,0)}
}
@media all and (min-width:1024px){html.mm-opening .mm-slideout{-webkit-transform:translate3d(440px,0,0);transform:translate3d(440px,0,0)}
}
```